# Placing a UIButton in the same space as UITabBar (When hidden)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UITabBarController` based application that I am developing. In one of my screen designs, I need to hide the tab bar (Which I do with `UIView`'s `setHidden` method) I then placed a UIView where the `tabBar` would normally be and added a `UIButton` to the `UIView`. However when tapping the button I do not get any response. The button does not receive any touch events.

I've looked at some SO questions and answers for the solution. However most of them require subclassing. I've tried subclassing and overriding the HitTest event, however even that method is not called in my UIButton subclass.

I'm developing on iOS 7.1.

Can anyone shed some light on this and how to get the button to respond to touch events?

**EDIT**

My self and @Geet have looked at this issue a little more closely. It seems anything placed in the same space as the `UITabBar` does not receive touch events. As a test I created a new project with very little code that replicates my original projects setup.

In the sample app, we have one `UIViewController` embedded in a `UITabBarController` as the first tab. That `UIViewController` is then embedded in a `UINavigationController`. From there, we push a second `UIViewController` onto the stack.

Tapping the "Hide Tabbar" button at the top does just that. Hides the tabBar. Which exposes the green `UIView` that has been placed there in the `storyboard`, with a `UIButton` that is connected to the `ViewControllers` implementation file. This button does not receive any touch events at all. As soon as I move the button above the space where the TabBar would normally occupy, the button works. Move it back down towards the bottom of the screen - button no longer works.

It seems Apple has barred all touch events under the `UITabBar`. I wonder if there is a way around this?

I have tried:

```
self.tabbar.userInteractionENabled = NO;
```

Which did not help either.

Maybe there is a method that we are able to override the in a subclass of `UITabbarController` that will allow touches in this spec when the `UITabBar` is hidden?

If anyone wants to play around with the sample project - its here on my gitHub:

https://github.com/TanderZA/UIButton-in-UITabbar-Space

Comment: Do you mean that you're not using UITabBarController's tab bar? Is the UIView which is a parent view of the UIButton a type of UIImageView?

Comment: Can you post some of your code .

Comment: Correct, I am hiding the UITabBarController's tab ba. I placed a UIView on my storyboard where the UITabBarController's tab bar would normally sit. When i side the tabBar - i can see the UIView I placed there. However the bottom I placed in that view doesn't respond to touched. Unless  touch the button right on its top edge. Which makes me this iOS doesn't allow touches at the bottom of the screen. There must be a work around?

Comment: @Geet There is hardly any code. All I do is self.tabbarController.tabBar.hidden = YES. Then I can see the UIView I placed behind the tabBar space in the storyboard. I then connected the UIButton in the view to my viewController file. If I move the UIView  a few points towards the top of the screen -the button starts working.

Comment: Have you added the button within the view or on top of the view, make sure that button is on top and the view is below the button

Comment: I have added the button onto of the UIView that I placed under the tabbar and I have tried adding it ontop of the view. Still nothing. If I touch the very edge of the button sometimes it responds. Is it maybe to do with Apple UIGesture control for the control centre that a user can bring up?

Comment: No, I dot think so, something is cancelling your touch event, have you added any touch guesture to your view

Comment: I've updated my question on what the view looks like. No gestures added to this view controller either. Its very odd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58141/discussion-between-geet-and-tander).

Comment: @geet sorry for my late reply. I am in chat now.

Comment: would really appreciate if some one could explain to us bat this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58186/discussion-between-geet-and-tander).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tander I finally figured it out, The button was not responding because its not receiving our touch events, you see In our storyboard, the View is not connected to the viewController, and due to this when I add the button programmatically to View It would never respond, A simple line solved this

In the function

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
```

Just do this

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    /* Will hide or unhide the tabBar */

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
    [self.tabBarController setTabBarItem:nil];

    UIButton *butt=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    butt.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    butt.frame=CGRectMake(160, 530, 93, 40);
    [butt addTarget:self action:@selector(testButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:butt];



}
```

the `self.tabBarController.view` was our culprit, not letting the touch Events pas through, glad to have figured it out

Comment: That's pretty impressive. Thank you for figuring it out! :D. This has saved me a lot of work with my other solution I was going to implement!

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered this myself, and in my case adding views to `self.tabBarController.view` was not an option.

Setting the tabBar as translucent (in addition to hiding it) allowed the touches to go through.

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: Nice. I will try this out and see if it works as I too would like to remove the subviews in UITabBar.

Comment: Still working in our code with iOS 9 GM. What seems new to iOS 9 is that if you don't set it translucent is that you get a big opaque space where the hidden tab bar is, which actually makes the problem obvious (as to why touches are not going through).

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this problem where we were hiding the `UITabBar` using `isHidden` but a `UIView` in one of the child view controllers underneath the `UITabBar` would not receive hit events. It received events everywhere but where the `UITabBar` used to be visible and located.

Rotating the phone back and forth would make the problem go away.  The solution I eventually found is after setting `isHidden` to `true` you need to call `setNeedsLayout` on the `UITabBarController` view:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden = true;
self.tabBarController.view.setNeedsLayout();
```